# Morse code cryptogram

Tags: cipher

Ciphertext: 1010, 111, 11, 0110, 001, 1, 0, 010, 000

This cryptogram is based off of AE's first one. Enjoy.

The answer to this is a clue to [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4668/the-security-to-the-party-part-30-1) which is currently unanswered and has a bounty.

**Technical Stuff**

No Roman numerals
No abbreviations
No slang or shorthands
Answer is relatively short...

Have fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think it's `COMPUTERS`. If you translate 0 as dot and 1 as dash in Morse code, except the `0011` needs to be split as `001` (U) and `1` (T). There's no Morse code symbol for `0011`. Edit: The dash character `-` is apparently encoded by `0011` so possibly `COMP-ERS`?

Comment: Correct, computers is right.

Comment: Why did I put the morse code part in the title? I get a weird feeling my friend pranked me.