# Vigenere text cipher

Tags: encoded-message, cipher

Cipher: Udfwavk wcfo nt "zjljhydmu"

This cipher is a solution to [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4668/the-security-to-the-party-part-30-1) which is currently unsolved and has a bounty.

Clarifications:

This is a special cipher, a Vigenere cipher, with this riddle telling the secret key:

All of are given this at birth,
it denotes each other apart,
you can find my profile with this,
and as such, it is my profile's ____

Chat is open: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18815/hard-text-cipher

Comment: Why the downvote? This is not unclear or anything...

Comment: I downvoted this because I don't like how it's already part of another question. You're splitting one question/riddle into multiple questions.

Comment: @Ric AE is doing it...

Comment: Yeah. I don't like that either. I guess we have a problem in that this behavior hasn't been defined as OK or not in this board. It's an odd/new situation that doesn't really apply anywhere else on SE. I'm going to take back my downvote and try to bring it up on the meta sometime soon.

Comment: @Ric I agree. While this is not technically splitting questions into two, I don't know if the community thinks it is okay. Post the meta question soon!

Comment: Here you go: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1499/spliiting-a-riddle-acroos-multiple-questions

Comment: I downvoted because this is one of those mass-producible puzzles I was talking about.

Comment: In addition to reasons others have given, I downvoted because it feels like a bait-and-switch. The title is "Vigenere text cipher". I'm quite a fan of doing cryptanalysis of Vigenere ciphers, but here it seems all you do is solve the riddle, after which decoding the cipher with the key is a superfluous and rote step. There's no real way to crack such a short Vigenere cipher without knowing the key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer is:

> DIGITAL ROOT OF SOMETHING.

Explanation: we are all given

> a name

at birth, so the secret key is

> your profile's name, namely 'QUYNGUYEN'.

Shove this into [a Vigenere decoder](http://sharkysoft.com/vigenere/), with the given ciphertext, and the answer comes out as stated.

Comment: Correct! You are right!

Comment: So now back to the party...